# Java Thread: Real world Application Example

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked a question in an interview, where i have list available in the main method and and i was told there is some operation to be performed on each item in the list, how would i achieve this using threads concept.
Consider the following scenario:
I have a list of integers. I need to print all the values from the list. Can it be done using threads concept where i have multiple threads running on each item in the list and where each thread is used to print out a value rather than one thread printing all the values? I am not trying to modify any value in the list.

Comment: It can be done, but it would be a very poor example of multithreading.

Comment: i am trying to understand the advantage of threads. i mostly see the printing values in a loop example which is not very enlightening. i was asked a similar question in an interview.

Comment: threads that block each other while printing out the values not give you any advantage of using threads.

Comment: "real time" = consistent latency, "real world" = a practical example.

Comment: ‘Real-time’ has a specific meaning in computing, and this isn’t it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a typical *producer-consumer* paradigm:

Imagine a Runnable class who receives an Iterator as parameter, and waits over a certain monitor, and then consumes one item from the iterator, and last notifies the same monitor. Loops while the iterator has more items.

Upon this, it will be enough to create the list of numbers, create the consumer threads passing them the list's iterator, and start them.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not tested at all. It's just something that comes into mind. The last implementation using parallelStream() might be what you are looking for.

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> myIntegerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

        // Good old for-each-loop
        for (Integer item : myIntegerList) {
            System.out.print(item);
        }

        // Java 8 forEach with Consumer
        final Consumer<Integer> consumer = new Consumer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Integer item) {
                System.out.print(item);
            }
        };

        myIntegerList.forEach(consumer);

        // Java 8 forEach with Lambda
        myIntegerList.forEach((item) -> System.out.print(item));

        // Java 8 forEach on parallelStream with Lambda
        myIntegerList.parallelStream().forEach((item) -> System.out.print(item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to understand the advantage of threads.

There are basically two reasons for using multiple threads in a program:

**(1) Asynchronous event handling:**  Imagine a program that must wait for and respond to several different kinds of input, and each kind of input can happen at completely arbitrary times.

Before threads, we used to write a big *event loop*, that would *poll* for each different kind of *event*, and then *dispatch* to different *handler* functions.  Things could start to get ugly when one or more of the event handlers was *stateful* (i.e., what it did next would depend on the history of previous events.)

A program that has one thread for each different kind of event often is much cleaner.  That is to say, it's easier to understand, easier to modify, etc.  Each thread loops waiting for just one kind of event, and its state (if any) can be kept in local variables, or its state can be implicit (i.e., depends on what function the thread is in at any given time).

(**2) Multiprocessing** (a.k.a., "parallel processing", "concurrent programming",...):  Using *worker threads* to perform *background computations* probably is the most widespread model of multiprocessing in use at this moment in time.

Multithreading is the lowest-level of all multiprocessing models which means (a) it is the hardest to understand, but (b) it is the most versatile.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. We can make use of concurrenthashmap. We can add the list to this map and pass it to the threads. Each thread will try to get the lock on the resource to operate.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are looking for something like that:

```
public class MaltiThreadExample {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

        for (int i : list) {
            Thread th = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            };
            th.start();
        }
    }

}
```

The output is for one execution:

```
run:
3
1
2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: This is not like the same, the order is different.

Comment: It is normal since multi-threading is coupled with asynchronous aspect

Comment: In this case it's wrong answer, because it doesn't follow the scenario: single thread is printing the list in the order defined by the list's index.

Comment: But, in the question, it is not required to print the list items ordred

Comment: If you use one thread then to print all items from the list with foreach loop the items will be printed in order. When you print all the items from the list with multiple threads the order is missing. Can you modify the code to print the list the same way like it's printed with a single thread?

Comment: It will be a bit complicated and with no sense to use multi-threading. Because the advantage of it is to enable working with threads each a part from the other (of course there are some special cases like pipelines which invoke dependence of threads).

Comment: It has no advantage unless you use non-blocking IO, the fact that it prints differently by this code, and can be used to prove that the code doesn't fulfill the requirements of the question. Saying that printing with multiple threads instead of one thread implies that it should print them equally.